# Setting up ggplot for a logistic regression with one predictor and looping through multiple outcomes (or columns)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, logistic-regression

I am a novice at R and have a ggplot related question. Below is a dummy data frame with one column containing the predictor (xvar) and multiple columns of dichotomous outcomes (yvar1, yvar2, yvar3).

```
df <- data.frame("xvar"=c(0,100,200,300,400,500,600,1000),"yvar1"= c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1),"yvar2"=c(0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1),"yvar3"=c(0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1))
```

I have created a *for* loop to run a logistic regression for each *yvar* against the predictor *xvar*. I am able to successfully plot the regression for each *yvar*. Please ignore the regression warnings (this is a dummy dataset)

```
for (i in 2:4) {

  logr.yvar <- glm(df[,names(df[i])] ~ xvar, data=df, family=binomial(link="logit"))
  print(logr.yvar)

  plot(df$xvar, df[,i])
  curve(predict(logr.yvar, data.frame(xvar=x), type="response"), add=TRUE) 

}
```

Instead of using the base *plot* function, I would like to switch to ggplot2. I am currently able to generate ggplots for individual regressions:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=xvar, y=yvar1)) + geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(method="glm", family="binomial", se=TRUE)
```

**How can I set up looping using ggplot2**?

Comment: Is the following code my best option  `plotHistFunc <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE, ...) {
  nm <- names(x)
  for (i in seq_along(nm)[2:4]) {
    print(ggplot(x,aes_string(x = nm[1], y=nm[i])) + geom_point() + 
      stat_smooth(method="glm", family="binomial", se=TRUE))
  }
}

plotHistFunc(df)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to loop, you could use `lapply`.

```
p <- lapply(names(df)[-1], function(nm){
  ggplot(df, aes_string(x="xvar", y=nm)) + geom_point() + 
    stat_smooth(method="glm", family="binomial", se=TRUE)
})
print(p)
```

However, I suspect that reshaping your data and displaying all the graphs together may be better.

```
# reshaping data
require(reshape2)
df.melt <- melt(df, id.var='xvar')
# first variation, using facets 
ggplot(df.melt, aes(xvar, value)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(method="glm", family="binomial", se=TRUE) +
  facet_grid(variable~.)
# second variation using colors
ggplot(df.melt, aes(xvar, value)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(aes(color = variable, fill = variable), 
              method="glm", family="binomial", se=TRUE, size = 1.2)
```